# $scope.watchCollection with if statements removes array data

Tags: angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope, watch

So I am running into a bit of confusion with the watchCollection statement. I am running an watching a change in an my array objects and I am noticing whenever I use an if statement within the $watch function, I remove 1 element of my array. I am confused why the $watchCollection function is an iterative process in which in reruns for the length of the array. I have this simple watch function below:

```
            scope.$watchCollection('waypoints', function () {
                if (scope.waypoints.length > 1) {
                    if (scope.waypoints[scope.waypoints.length - 1] == "`") {
                        scope.waypoints.pop();
                    }
                    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, scope.waypoints);
                }
            });
```

When I run the if statement I lose an element from the array. I even created a jsfiddle with a debugger showing that $watch function reiterates itself for the length of the array http://jsfiddle.net/kL6909to/.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope), the watched argument (the first argument to `$watchCollection`) is as follows:

> The obj collection is observed via standard $watch operation and is
>   examined on every call to $digest() to see if any items have been
>   added, removed, or moved.

It isn't enough for the watcher to just verify that the length has changed.  Rather, it must iterate the array to check not only length, but to check whether or not any elements in that array have been modified, as well as their position within the watched array.  This will occur for every single modification to the collection.

Comment: That makes sense for the $watch itself, but in regards to the if statements. I notice that for every if statement, an element is removed from my array. why is that? For example, if I had 2 if statements in the $watch function, I lose 2 elements in the array before I am able to run my calculateAndDisplayRoute function.

Comment: @JuliusDoan your jsfiddle doesn't concisely reproduce your post.  Are you able to post a more concise fiddle that demonstrates the behavior you're seeing, along with clarification on why it isn't behaving as expected?

Comment: Sry the is jsfiddle was for my first question regarding the digest(). I will update the jsfiddle and try to recreate the issue with the loss of array with the if statements.

Comment: @JuliusDoan Much appreciated!  That would be very helpful